# Application Continuity with Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

Good day,

I need to ensure the application continuity using the feature from Oracle ojdbc7 12.1.0.2. I have thousands of project where I use Spring and Hibernate to access the db an manage the transactions.
To implement the application continuity feature in my projects, I have to use this class **oracle.jdbc.replay.ReplayableConnection** . So actually I don't know how to instruct Spring (and Hibernate) to use this class to manage transactions using the **@Transactional** annotation.

Actually, what I am doing is:

1. declaring the datasource (this implementation has the ReplayableConnection class)

   ```
   @Bean
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
   public DataSource oracleDataSource() throws SQLException {

       OracleDataSourceImpl oracleDataSource = new OracleDataSourceImpl();

       oracleDataSource.setUser(datasourceUsername);
       oracleDataSource.setPassword(datasourcePassword);
       oracleDataSource.setURL(datasourceUrl);
       oracleDataSource.setDataSourceName("OracleDataSourceImpl");

       return oracleDataSource;
   }
   ```
2. Autowiring the datasource where I need it

   ```
   @Resource(name = "oracleDataSource")
   private DataSource dataSource;

   @Autowired
   private BdtContRepository bdtContRepository;

   @Override
   public void updateRow() {
       logger.info("updateRow -> finding all rows...");
       Iterable<BdtCont> bdtConts = bdtContRepository.findAll();

       try {
           if (this.dataSource.getConnection() instanceof oracle.jdbc.replay.ReplayableConnection) {
               ((oracle.jdbc.replay.ReplayableConnection)this.dataSource.getConnection()).beginRequest();

               logger.info("updateRow -> updating all rows...");

               StreamSupport.stream(bdtConts.spliterator(), false)
                       ...
                       });

               logger.info("updateRow -> done");

             ((oracle.jdbc.replay.ReplayableConnection)this.dataSource.getConnection()).endRequest();

           }
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

   }
   ```

   }

As you can see I am manually managing transactions using BeginRequest and EndRequest. In this case it doesn't work; it doesn't ensure the application continuity neither a simple rollback.

Is there a way to instruct Spring to use that kind of class to manage transactions?

**UPDATE 30/01/2018**
Here my Spring configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String datasourceUrl;

@Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
private String datasourceUsername;

@Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
private String datasourcePassword;

@Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
private String driverClassName;

@Value("${spring.jpa.database-platform}")
private String databasePlatform;

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource oracleDataSource() throws SQLException {

    OracleDataSourceImpl oracleDataSource = new OracleDataSourceImpl();

    oracleDataSource.setUser(datasourceUsername);
    oracleDataSource.setPassword(datasourcePassword);
    oracleDataSource.setURL(datasourceUrl);
    oracleDataSource.setDataSourceName("OracleDataSourceImpl");

    return oracleDataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(oracleDataSource());
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.example.demotx.domain");
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(databasePlatform);
    jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    return jpaVendorAdapter;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() throws SQLException {
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    jpaTransactionManager.setDataSource(oracleDataSource());
    return jpaTransactionManager;
}

@Bean
public OracleTransactionCoordinator transactionCoordinator() throws SQLException {
    return new OracleTransactionCoordinator(oracleDataSource(),jpaTransactionManager());
}
```

If I launch the application with the current configuration, when I shut down an oracle node it says :  SQL exception 17410 No more data to read from socket.
(Actually I have two nodes and I shut down the node where it connects)

**UPDATE 31/01/2018**
I setup a little project where I use the same type of classes that I need to use for my old projects. As yu can see I switched to the explicit calls to begin request and end request.

Here I have my TransactionCoordinator that access the database and provides rollbacks mechanism on exceptions

```
@Component
public class OracleTransactionCoordinator {

private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OracleTransactionCoordinator.class);

private final OracleDataSource oracleDataSource;

private final PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager;

@Autowired
public OracleTransactionCoordinator(OracleDataSource oracleDataSource, PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager) {
    this.oracleDataSource = oracleDataSource;
    this.jpaTransactionManager = jpaTransactionManager;
}

/**
 * Execute a portion of code in transaction, with transaction behaviour {@link org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition} PROPAGATION_REQUIRED.
 *
 * @param context a callback support instance.
 * @param <R>     type of result.
 * @return typed result of callback.
 */
public final <R> R doInTransaction(final ExecutionContext<R> context) throws SQLException {
    return doInTransaction(context, true);
}

/**
 * Execute a portion of code in transaction.
 *
 * @param context   a callback support instance.
 * @param propagate true to use PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, false to use PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW.
 * @param <R>       type of result.
 * @return typed result of callback.
 */
public final <R> R doInTransaction(final ExecutionContext<R> context, final boolean propagate) throws SQLException {
    TransactionTemplate tx = new TransactionTemplate(jpaTransactionManager);
    Connection connection = oracleDataSource.getConnection();
    try {
        ((OracleConnection) connection).beginRequest();
        if (propagate) {
            tx.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED);
        } else {
            tx.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        }
        R result = tx.execute(new TransactionCallback<R>() {

            @Override
            public R doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                context.setTransactionStatus(status);
                R result = context.doInTransaction();
                context.setRollback(status.isRollbackOnly());
                return result;
            }

        });
        context.close(null);
        return result;
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        LOG.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        context.setRollback(true);
        context.close(ex);
        return null;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        context.setRollback(true);
        context.close(new RuntimeException("Wrapper pool exception", ex));
        return null;

    } finally {
        try {
            if (tx != null) {
                ((OracleConnection) connection).endRequest();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignored
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Transactional callback support class.
 *
 * @param <R> result type.
 */
public abstract static class ExecutionContext<R> {

    private final Queue<Runnable> afterCommitCommands = new LinkedList<Runnable>();
    private final Queue<Runnable> afterRollbackCommands = new LinkedList<Runnable>();
    private TransactionStatus transactionStatus = null;
    private boolean rollback = false;
    private boolean rethrow = true;

    public void setTransactionStatus(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
        this.transactionStatus = transactionStatus;
    }

    public void setRollback(boolean rollback) {
        this.rollback = rollback;
    }

    public void setRethrow(boolean rethrow) {
        this.rethrow = rethrow;
    }

    public void close(RuntimeException error) {
        if (!rollback) {
            for (Runnable command : afterCommitCommands) {
                try {
                    command.run();
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    LOG.error("Attention an after commit command has gone in error!!! Please check it!", e);
                }
            }
            afterCommitCommands.clear();
        } else {
            for (Runnable command : afterRollbackCommands) {
                try {
                    command.run();
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    LOG.error("Attention an after rollback command has gone in error!!! Please check it!", e);
                }
            }
            afterRollbackCommands.clear();
        }
        if (error != null && rethrow) {
            throw error;
        }
    }

    protected abstract R doInTransaction();

    protected void doAfterCommit(Runnable command) {
        afterCommitCommands.offer(command);
    }

    protected void doAfterRollback(Runnable command) {
        afterRollbackCommands.offer(command);
    }

    protected void rollbackTransaction() {
        transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly();
    }

    protected void flush() {
        transactionStatus.flush();
    }

}

private final static class TransactionTemplateFactory extends BasePoolableObjectFactory<TransactionTemplate> {
    private final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    public TransactionTemplateFactory(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
    }

    public TransactionTemplate makeObject() {
        return new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    }

}
```

The usage of the OracleTransactionCoordinator is pretty straightforward: 
 My Main class:

```
transactionCoordinator.doInTransaction(new OracleTransactionCoordinator.ExecutionContext<Object>() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInTransaction() {
                instanceRepository.findAll().forEach(ins -> logger.info("instance name: "+ ins.toString()));
                logger.info("do In Transaction... updating all");
                bdtContRepository.updateAll();
                instanceRepository.findAll().forEach(ins -> logger.info("instance name: "+ ins.toString()));
                logger.info("FINISHED");
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Acually, If I launch this and I shut down the oracle node where it connects it says:

```
2018-01-31 13:55:54.077  INFO 8114 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: select instance0_.INSTANCE_NAME as INSTANCE_NAME1_1_ from CURR_INST instance0_
2018-01-31 13:55:54.422  INFO 8114 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.example.demotx.DemoTxApplication     : instance name: Instance{instanceName='LABLAR2'}
2018-01-31 13:55:54.422  INFO 8114 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.example.demotx.DemoTxApplication     : do In Transaction... updating all
Hibernate: update BDT_CONT set VAL=?
2018-01-31 13:55:55.602  WARN 8114 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 17410, SQLState: 08000
2018-01-31 13:55:55.602 ERROR 8114 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : No more data to read from socket
2018-01-31 13:55:55.602  WARN 8114 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 17370, SQLState: 99999
2018-01-31 13:55:55.603 ERROR 8114 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Replay disabled:
2018-01-31 13:55:55.626 ERROR 8114 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.t.support.TransactionTemplate        : Application exception overridden by rollback exception

org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: c
ould not execute statement
```

As you can see it says "replay disabled" and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: this won't get Spring to manage the transactions. you typically annotate your repository interface w/ @Transactional. but. to make this code work in the way you want it to: it looks as if you're operating on 2 different connections. why are you not saving your the results of your (oracle.jdbc.replay.ReplayableConnection)this.dataSource.getConnection()) to a variable like replayConnection & calling something like: replayConnection.beginRequest() and replayConnection.endRequest(); ??

Comment: I was just trying using that kind of class; insted of using transactions manually, I would like to know if I can alter the behavior of the @Transactional annotation making it to use replayableConnection.beginRequest() and endRequest() instead of the default mechanism of rollback. (with the application continuity when a Oracle node goes down, the driver automatically switch to another node and continues the job).

Comment: i think what you want is to try to configure the connection class used in your connection pool. that's doable. @Transactional will do a rollback on whatever questions you give it. what does replayConnection.begin/endRequest do under the heard that's any different than the JPA managed rollback mechanism? have you found the fail over doesn't work this way?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to achieve. the replayConnection.begin/endRequest is different from the jpa managed rollback: with the replayableConnection if the connection to the db goes down (so the oracle node goes down) it automatically tries to connect to another oracle node, creates a connection and continues the transaction.
Actually, with the actual configuration it doesn't work that way but it does a simple rollback (it says "oops, the socket to the db is closed, rolling back..")

Comment: I am not sure if you know how this mechanism works. It is described in detail in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/appcontnew.htm#JJDBC2907)  how to configure the database and JDBC connections to make it work. In short - you don't need and even should not touch Hibernate/Spring, the whole mechanizm works at JDBC connection pool level. These methods should be called when borrowing and returning the JDBC connection from/to the pool. If you are using OracleDataSource or UCP, these calls are done automatically.

Comment: yes, but i think what he's asking is will the rollback() automatically result in a retry the same way it would w/ a ReplayConnection? or will jpa just rollback the connection without the retry? i'm sure JPA will rollback the connection properly. retry? hmm... i don't know.

@Justin have you set up a little test to see what the behavior will actually be? you can have an oracle DB & a query generator & shutdown the DB mid-stream. you'll find out what happens then.

Comment: Yes, I was meaning that. The default jpa transaction manager behavior will rollback the transaction and will give an exception ("oops no more data from the socket...") but I don't want this. I want to tell to spring to use that ReplayableConnection under the hood.
For the example, see above ( I have updated the question with my Spring Database configuration)

Comment: @Justin have you set up a test to see what actually happens?

Comment: @DieNerd Yes, I did. Actually I am using one of my projects and trying to switch to the replay driver. 
I have updated the question with the current setup and classes.